# could not set ad-hoc mode on wlan0. operation not supported on transport endpoint

Tags: wifi-tethering, ad-hoc-networks

Triing to use [Barnacle Wifi Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.szym.barnacle&hl=en) on Samsung Galaxy Note2 GT-N7100. And when I press start wifi tether, got error: `could 'not set ad-hoc mode on wlan0. operation not supported on transport endpoint'` And then: `Could not connect to NAT, will retry later`. Using other wifi tethers apps also got troubles. My phone is rooted and got [custom firmware android 4.2.2](http://www.gogadgetx.com/how-to-update-samsung-galaxy-note-2-to-android-4-2-2-jelly-bean-international-att-t-mobile-and-verizon/#)

[image: Barnacle Wifi Tether printscreen: could 'not set ad-hoc mode on wlan0. operation not supported on transport endpoint']
<sup>Barnacle Wifi Tether printscreen: could 'not set ad-hoc mode on wlan0. operation not supported on transport endpoint' (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install  [this wifi tether](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/apk/wifitether/treve) and configure it according to [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=qT3Rx0OppQY). It's working